# textarea in IE7 : can't make a carriage return

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, textarea

i'm using a textarea in a webpage which is loaded through an Ajax request.
The result of the request is a list of numbers separated by `\n`

Here is the result :

```
<textarea wrap="hard" rows="10" cols="80">111000333
414141411
</textarea>
```

In Chrome it works correctly but in IE7 the carriage return doesn't work and all the result is on the same line.

What can i do ? use another way of making carriage return or add properties to the textarea ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `\r\n` instead of just `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

could you use javascript regex?  i.e. str.replace(/\r\n/gi, "
")

where str is the innerHTML of the textarea

Comment: try this link for a css way of doing this also: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=326092.0